# Equivalent of grep -v -f -F using sed?

Tags: bash, performance, shell, sed, grep

I would like to use sed instead of grep because of `set -e` presence in my shell script.

I am using grep -v -f -F to filter some patterns from a file file1.txt like,

```
grep -v -f -F file.txt data.txt > filtereddata.txt
```

This will filter the data which is not matching the pattern in file.txt.
I need to do this using sed. I was able to find invert match using `'//p!'` in sed but could not find combination of -f with `'//p!'`.

Is above grep command possible using sed with equivalent or better performance?

Comment: You can keep a failed `grep` from bombing out your script due to `set -e` by putting  `|| true` on the end of the command.  This also works for any other command whose exit code should not abort the script.

Comment: I think @MarkReed's solution is the right one.  Also, if you plan on using `set -e`, you will want to read the Bash FAQ: [Why doesn't set -e (or set -o errexit, or trap ERR) do what I expected?](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105).

Comment: I am working on doing it using grep ... || true but meanwhile I thought of using it with sed. Can you please provide the same output using sed command?

Comment: `sed` doesn't have a non-regex match option

Comment: This user's [earlier question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33679169/258523) is useful as background here (where I discuss `set -e` workarounds and that Bash FAQ entry).